# How to send generated passkit to Wallet?

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit

I generated a  passbok file in Java that I want to share with the wallet applications in iOS and Android. The method creates a 
.pkpass file so... how can I send it to the Wallet applications? I find really few information about this step...

Comment: in Java? Physical passbook? I think I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself REALLY bad... sorry. I want this passbook to be sent to my wallet. I wanted to say I generate the digital pass in code (the .pkpass file).

Comment: how to generate pass on serverside and what serverside will return me back

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you created pkpass file in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can email it to users or put it on a web server with a header `Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.  Or you can use the [PKAddPassesViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpassesviewcontroller) to add to Wallet via an app.